# c++11 array initialization won't call copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, uniform-initialization, stdarray

I'm making a little class that uses an array templated on its size. Here's some code...

.hpp

```
template <size_t N>
class KeyCombinationListener
{
public:
    KeyCombinationListener(
        const std::array<sf::Keyboard::Key, N>& sequence,
        std::function<void (void)> fn
        );

private:
    std::array<sf::Keyboard::Key, N>  combo;
    std::function<void (void)>  callback;
};
```

.cc

```
template <size_t N>
KeyCombinationListener<N>::KeyCombinationListener(
    const array<sf::Keyboard::Key, N>& sequence, function<void (void)> fn
    ) : combo(sequence), progress{begin(combo)}, callback{fn}
{

}
```

In the member initialization of the constructor, I can't use `combo{sequence}` as the initializer because it only accepts `sf::Keyboard::Key` types. This makes sense if it's asking for an `initializer_list`, but this seems strange to me. With other standard containers I can call a copy constructor using {} notation just fine. Is this a quirk with `std::array`? Or maybe a bug in my clang?

Just in case it helps, here's my clang version:

```
Debian clang version 3.5.0-10 (tags/RELEASE_350/final) (based on LLVM 3.5.0)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.2
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.2
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
```

Comment: It's a quirk of `std::array` and a defect in C++14. That container is required to be an aggregate, and list-initialization with single elements was defective in C++14. See http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1467

Comment: @dyp Ok, thanks. Does this mean I can expect to see a fix in C++17?

Comment: The proposed resolution does appear in recent drafts, so I expect it to be fixed in the next Standard revision.

Comment: Btw, this has nothing to do with `std::initializer_list`. That's a class template that is intended to simplify certain initializations from *braced-init-lists*. The latter is the grammatical name of the `{..}` initializer construct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've encountered a defect in C++: list-initialization from a single element. The behaviour specified in the C++11 and C++14 International Standard is surprising. I'll refer to C++14 below.

Template instantiations of `std::array` are aggregates <sup>[array.overview]/2</sup>. Therefore, when initializing `std::array` objects from a *braced-init-list*, *aggregate-initialization* will be performed indiscriminately of the number of initializers <sup>[dcl.init.list]/3.1</sup>. Other container classes cannot be aggregates because of the requirements for certain constructions (e.g. from a pair of iterators).

Aggregate-initialization initializes (potentially recursively) the data members from the initializers. In your case, it will try to initialize the first data member of `std::array<sf::Keyboard::Key, N>` from the initializer `sequence` (which is of the same type). For all implementations of `std::array` I know, the first data member of `std::array` is a C-style array. List-initialization will then try to initialize the first element of that array from the original initializer: `sequence`.

Example:

```
struct aggregate
{
    int m[2];
};

aggregate x = {0, 1};
assert(x.m[0] == 0 && x.m[1] == 1);

aggregate y{x}; // error: cannot convert `aggregate` to `int`
```

The initialization in the last line will try to initialize `y.m[0]` from `x`.

---

[CWG issue 1467](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1467) describes this and a related issue, list-initializing when there are no initializers. The proposed resolution introduces a (yet another) special case for list-initialization that covers the issue in the OP. Quoting a recent github draft, [dcl.init.list]/3.1

> If `T` is a class type and the initializer list has a single element of
>   type *cv* `U`, where `U` is `T` or a class derived from `T`, the object is
>   initialized from that element (by copy-initialization for
>   copy-list-initialization, or by direct-initialization for
>   direct-list-initialization).

Aggregate-initialization in recent drafts has lower "priority" (3.3), that is, will only be performed if the condition above is not met.

---

Recent versions of g++ (5.0) and clang++ (3.7.0) implement the proposed resolution even in C++11 mode.